# how to get rid of only /home when someone visits my site?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can some one help me here with htaccess?

Currently when someone visits my website somesite.com by default the url looks like somesite.com/home

I wish for it to only for home page to not show the /home instead show just https://www.somesite.com

here is my whole htaccess file

```
# Case 1
# -------------------------------------------------------#
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#  

# Case 2
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine on
# ExpiresActive On
# ExpiresDefault A2592000
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|backups|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt|curl.php)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 3
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# </IfModule>
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 4
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 6 for SSL Hosting
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine on
# ExpiresActive On
# ExpiresDefault A2592000
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# case 5
# -------------------------------------------------------#
#RewriteEngine On
#DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# secure GIT files
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
 mod_gzip_on Yes
 mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
 mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post in your question from which url to which url you want to redirect/rewrite for better understanding.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 only home page i wish to no show /home rest pages like site.com/contact or site.com/about-us should remain same only for home page which is index.php i do not want site.com/home

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i tried adding a line but website keeps refreshing. im unable to post it here i get too many codes not allowed while posting

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing these URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=302,L]
```

`R=302` is temporary redirection, to make it permanent redirection use `R=301` in above.

Comment: Do i need to remove any lines from my current htaccess?

Comment: it keeps refreshing the website

Comment: @Eveline, I think only rewriterule you have is for `index.php` one for non existing directories or files, may be you could try put this this rule after that, but honestly I tested only these rules and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this rule at top of your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [R=301,L,NC]

# remaining rules go below this
```